# Sqlce 3.5 needs to be installed to use it?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am using sqlce 3.5 (System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll) in my application. It works well when I install sqlce 3.5 setup in my machine (XP 32 bit) but it gives problem if i didn't install the sqlce 3.5 setup on my machine. Do we really need to install it ? I think instead of installing it, we can directly use its assembly ( System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll) to use it.

I am using .Net framework 2.0 to build the application. The error throws while I initialized the SqlCeConnection. Here is the code that throw exception when I don't install sqlce 3.5.

```
SqlCeConnection  _sqlCeConnection = new SqlCeConnection(_connectionString);
```

Comment: You can follow the guide here http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2012/05/private-deployment-of-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error when try to create a sqlce object

Unable to load the native components of SQL Server Compac
t corresponding to the ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Install the correct ver
sion of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.

and Here is my app.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="exporterUserCacheDB" connectionString="Data Source=UserCacheDBSkeleton.sdf;mode=Read Write;max database size=4091;temp file max size=4091" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"/>
```